# How to prevent Rails 2.3.8 from checking all dependencies while loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I have a rails 2.3.8 app which can be started without database. so in the environment.rb file i exclude ActiveRecord and in the application controller i render different pages when ActiveRecord is not defined. But when i try to upgrade mongral to passenger, passenger throws an Error

> uninitialized constant ActiveRecord

The control is not going to the application controller at all. How can i make passenger not raise this exception.?

Attached the stacktrace

http://pastebin.com/1kXDwiRT

in abuses.rb i have

> class Abuse < ActiveRecord::Base
>   acts_as_paranoid
>
> belongs_to :user   belongs_to
>   :review   validates_presence_of :type,
>   :message => _('cannot be blank')
>   validates_presence_of :user, :on =>
>   :create, :if => Proc.new { |r|
>   r.visitor_id == nil}
>   validates_presence_of :visitor_id, :on
>   => :create, :if => Proc.new { |r| r.user_id == nil}
>   validates_length_of :comment, :maximum
>   => 2000, :message => _('is too long 2000')
>
> end

I cannot remove this model classes because they will be used when i start the website with ActiveRecord. I want to start the website without ActiveRecord in some emergency situation where the db is down. and i ll show the pages which doesnt database.

After further more researching i found that in 
intializer.rb file i have this function

> def load_application_classes
>         return if $rails_rake_task
>         if configuration.cache_classes
>           configuration.eager_load_paths.each do
>   |load_path|
>             matcher = /\A#{Regexp.escape(load_path)}(.*).rb\Z/
>             Dir.glob("#{load_path}/**/*.rb").sort.each
>   do |file|
>               require_dependency file.sub(matcher, '\1')
>             end
>           end
>         end
>       end

commenting out the require_dependency line, makes the rails not to check Dependency of each and every file. Is there any way to disable this from the environment.rb config file?
setting config.cache to false is working. but i want to cache the classes. but only not check the dependency.

Comment: have attached the stack trace.

Comment: What do you have here: /app/models/abuse.rb 16 ?

Comment: Or here: /config/environment.rb 14?

Comment: Ahaa.. I thought you were developing app which does not use ActiveRecord at all. I think that kind of "half using" approach is pretty rare. What's the reason behind it?

Comment: There are few imp features of our website which doenst require a database. like, we query another request server to show results for user input. so in emergency conditions when the database is down. we atleast want to keep the non-db part of the website running. hence such a requirement.

Comment: Perhaps you could use rescue to make require_dependency fail silently and then in your code check if the db connection is alive. This setup sounds really hackish to me though. I'd try to separate the functionality into two separate apps, but because its not Rails 3 its probably harder to achieve.